# powerbi-client-react - Property 'getPages' does not exist on type 'Embed'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am using powerbi-client-react in a typescript project.
I wanna use the ***report*** instance to read out the from/to values of a date-slicer on an active page. the problem is, when I am setting the getEmbeddedComponent attribute on my PowerBIEmbed component, then the handed report has **not all** methods that are listed in the powerbi javascript api docu. For example I need report.getPages() to access the slicer states but the method is not found on the report instance, which is of type embed.

Thx for any kind of help

```
            getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
              const pages = embeddedReport.getPages();
            }}
```

Answer (score 2):

For React wrapper, `getEmbeddedComponent` returns Embed object, which does not have the `getPages()` function on it.

If you want to use getPages(), then please typecast the `Embed` object as `Report`.

The following code snippet will work:

```js
getEmbeddedComponent = {(embedObject: Embed) => {
    const pages = (embedObject as Report).getPages();
}};
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-pages